# Relative folder path in git config core.sshCommand to specify a repo specific/deploy (ssh) key

Tags: ssh, git, github

I've been looking to specify the path to ssh key relative to the git directory.

It usually looks like this in `.git/config`:

```
[core]
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_repo -F /dev/null #-vvv #Uncomment -vvv for verbose output.
```

Can be set by editing the `.git/config` file or by running:
if another value already exists:
`git config --unset core.sshCommand`

```
sshCommand="ssh -i "$SCRIPT_DIR"/../.ssh/id_rsa_repo -F /dev/null"
git config core.sshCommand "$sshCommand"
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple fix:

```
sshCommand = ssh -i $(echo $PWD)/.ssh/id_rsa_repo -F /dev/null #-vvv #Uncomment -vvv for verbose output.
```

Also works with:

```
$(pwd)/.ssh/....
```

Hope this helps.